# Запрос к БД по дате

Tags: c#, sql, select

```
commanddb.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM testtab WHERE datatime ="
                         + datatimeDateEdit.Text;
```

Мне нужно сделать запрос к БД, что бы возвращало результаты заданой даты, а в табличе datetime имеет кроме даты еще время. Как это сделать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Не склеивайте вводимые пользователем значения в SQL. Используйте параметры. Тогда вопросы формата дат и настроек локали SQL сами собой отпадут. И заодно не наплодите sql-иньекций - мало ли что тами пользователь в текстбокс ведёт.

```
var datatime = DateTime.Parse(datatimeDateEdit.Text);

commanddb.CommandText = 
    "SELECT * FROM testtab WHERE datatime >= @from and datatime < @to";
commanddb.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", datatime);
commanddb.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", datatime.AddDays(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно привести к типу даты:

```
commanddb.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM testtab WHERE cast(datatime as date)="
                         + datatimeDateEdit.Text;
```